# Using Date in SOQL to get only records created on a certain date

Tags: soql, date

I'm using this soql query in my webservice to query for records created within specific dates and using this as an if condition of the dates are the same

```
if(fromDate == toDate){
          orderList = [SELECT Id,Name,Account__r.Kennitala__c ,Account__r.Name,Contact__r.Name,phPhoneNumberUsedForService__c,createdDate, RecordType.Name,txServiceOwnerName__c,pl_Status__c,txlOrderInfoFromWeb__c,CreatedBy.Name 
                    from Orders__c where Account__r.ktId__c =:request.str_ktId AND CreatedDate =: fromDate];
```

fromDate & toDate are values of type Date ands are retrieved from the request (This is a SOAP service).   What I'm seeing is that if I have the dates identical, f/x 2014-01-16, then I get nothing returned.  But if toDate is set to the date after, like 2014-01-17, then the query returns the records created on 2014-01-16 .  I tried doing this in my query tool using instances of DateTime and got the same result.

I'm just wondering, is this expected and do I have to account for this in queries when the from dates and to dates are the same since CreatedDate is DateTime and I'm passing in a Date in the request?

Comment: a related issue is here: http://force746.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/gotcha-converttimezone-must-be-used-in-soql-date-functions-dealing-with-datetime/

Comment: @crop1645 Wrote my answer before I saw your comment...

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried this method but couldn't get it to work.  What I did in the end was to create a special case for this type of qery and have the ToDate as FromDate.addDays(1).

Answer (score 2):

A likely cause of this is implicit conversion of CreatedDate to a Date producing an unexpected result because of the timezone set for your user. According to this [Gotcha: convertTimezone() must be used in SOQL Date functions dealing with Datetime](http://force746.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/gotcha-converttimezone-must-be-used-in-soql-date-functions-dealing-with-datetime/) blog post by my colleague, the right expression to use for the date part of the "where" is:

```
DAY_ONLY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) = :fromDate
```

Comment: This didn't work for me either, what I did was to catch this query and have it return records where toDate=fromdate.addDays(1)